# Access actor methods in modules?

Tags: codeception

Probably very simple, but can't figure it out.

How can you use methods from `tests/_support/AcceptanceTester.php` inside your helper modules?

For example when I'm in `tests/_support/Helper/Acceptance.php` I cannot reference any of the methods in `tests/_support/AcceptanceTester.php`

I'm assuming because one is an actor and the other is a module?

I read https://codeception.com/docs/06-ModulesAndHelpers but I still don't understand how this works.

### Update

Saw a [discussion on github](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/1443) that deals with this situation and it was suggested to use [StepObjects](https://codeception.com/docs/06-ReusingTestCode#StepObjects)

I managed to put both helper methods and actor methods into a StepObject class method, but that still doesn't work. It doesn't allow me to execute both from one place.

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of trying to find an 'elegant' solution to this problem such as using StepObjects injecting dependencies etc. it's much easier to just pass the **$I** object to whichever helper class method you're using..

It's more verbose, but it works.

If anyone has a better solution, I'll gladly accept it instead.